# Having problems with recover.c

Tags: c, cs50

I'm having problems trying to execute the following code correctly. The problem is that I am creating the exact number of JPEGs, and they seem to open correctly, except there is no image being shown. I'm doing recover.c of Pset4 in the course CS50.

```
/**
* A file that recovers lost JPEGs
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BLOCK 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[1];

    // open file 
    FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    FILE* outptr;
    uint8_t buffer[512];
    int count = 0;

    while (fread(buffer, BLOCK, 1, inptr))
    {

        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff
            && (buffer[3] == 0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1))
        {

            char filename[8];
            sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", count);
            outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
            count++;
            fwrite(&buffer, BLOCK, 1, outptr);

            if (outptr == NULL)
            {
                fclose(inptr);
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", filename);
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(outptr);
    fclose(inptr);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your error check for `outptr` is too late; things have already crashed if you failed to create the file.  Once you've detected the first block of a JPG file, don't you have to copy the body of the file to the output too?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way the images open correctly, since you only ever copy at most 512 bytes into each file, and I'm going to assume most images are larger than that.

This code:

```
outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
```

must go *outside* the `while(fread())` loop, you only want to open each output file once, not once per read block.

Also, the return value of `fread()` is very important here, and I/O should be binary.

Comment: By 'open correctly' I mean that it recognises the .jpeg extension and allows me to open them but does not display the picture. I've played the fopen() outside the while loop but am still having problems.

Comment: @zalidael And if you list the sizes of the output files, and compare them to the inputs, are they equal?

Comment: How do I go about listing the sizes?

Comment: Umm..  your OS, and its filesystem, and its shell/s will have a way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have fixed the code and found the answer to my problem. Here's the code if anyone's interested: Thanks to everyone who helped!

```
/**
 * A file that recovers lost JPEGs
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define BLOCK 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// ensure proper usage
if (argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover image\n");
    return 1;
}

// remember filenames
char *infile = argv[1];

// open file 
FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
    return 2;
}

FILE* outptr;
uint8_t buffer[512];
int count = 0;

// find lost images and write to outfile
while (fread(buffer, BLOCK, 1, inptr))
{
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff
        && (buffer[3] == 0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1))
    {
        char filename[8];
        sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", count);
        outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
        count++;

        if (outptr == NULL)
            {
                fclose(inptr);
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", filename);
                return 3;
            }

    }

if (outptr != NULL)
{
    fwrite(&buffer, BLOCK, 1, outptr);
}

}

fclose(outptr);
fclose(inptr);  

return 0;
}
```

Comment: File should be opened in binary mode, not text mode.  `char filename[8];` is too small should `count` exceed 999.  Recommend using `unsigned count` and a large enough buffer like `char filename[20 + 6];`

Comment: No need for `&` in `fwrite(&buffer, BLOCK, 1, outptr);`

Comment: @chux  'File should be opened in binary mode, not text mode.' What do you mean by that exactly? And how should I go about implementing it?

Comment: "r open text file for reading"  "rb open binary file for reading", "wb truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing" etc. --> `fopen(filename, "...b")`